# VBA button read and copy value to other cell

Tags: vba

```
Sub Button1Click()

Dim temp As Worksheet
Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

Dim tempAct As String
Dim tempCC As String
Dim tempRan As String

tempAct = Range("B1").Value
tempCC = Range("B2").Value
tempRan = Range("B3").Value

If temp.Range("B1:B3").Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Blank Input!")

ElseIf temp.Range("B1:B3").Value <> "" Then
temp.Range("C1").Value = tempAct
temp.Range("C2").Value = tempCC
tmep.Range("C3").Value = tempRan
End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to make a simple code when pressing this button, it will simply copy the cell value onto the other cell, and also any idea how to put the input result in the listbox?

I am getting Type Missmatch error when generating this macro.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: On another note, `tmep.Range("C3").Value = tempRan` has `temp` misspelled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the type mismatch is occurring because of this line

`If temp.Range("B1:B3").Value = "" Then`

I don't believe you can apply the condition to all of the cells in the range.  If your range was a single cell, i.e. `Range("B1").Value`, then the condition statement would be syntactically correct, but of course wouldn't give you the desired outcome.

You instead can use a `For` loop to test each cell as shown below.

```
Sub Button1Click()

    Dim temp As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Cancel As Boolean

    Cancel = False

    Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

    Dim tempAct As String
    Dim tempCC As String
    Dim tempRan As String

    tempAct = Range("B1").Value
    tempCC = Range("B2").Value
    tempRan = Range("B3").Value

    Set rng = temp.Range("B1:B3")
    For Each cell In rng
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            MsgBox ("Blank Input!")
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Cancel = False Then
        temp.Range("C1").Value = tempAct
        temp.Range("C2").Value = tempCC
        temp.Range("C3").Value = tempRan
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to put the user input on the other sheet and it will accumulate from row 1 and so on, how would I do this?

Comment: TEMP_COST would be the other sheet, and Lastrow As Long